# Magento 2.4 Cache won't really clear

Tags: magento, caching, magento2

i have a pretty fresh setup of a Magento 2.4 on a Google VM. I am however super confused regarding the Caching - or am looking for the issue on my side.

I have disabled all caches in Magento (and verified it with the CLI, all cache types are 0). I have cleared and flushed the cache and deleted all the mage--... folders in var/cache. I have also removed all content form the var/page_cache directory. After removing the flolders (rm -rf ..), the folders are empty - however, a few moments later, they are filled again with pretty much the same. I can't wrap my head around this - has anyone experienced a similar thing?

Thank you!
Best Jan